# isDisabled on react-native-modalbox does not work with onPress

Tags: react-native

I believe I am doing everything correctly. I am basically copying straight from the docs. Please let me know if I am calling it incorrectly.

My state

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      isDisabled: false
    }
  }
```

My modal

```
<Modal style={[styles.modal, styles.modal3]} position={"center"} ref={"modal3"} isDisabled={this.state.isDisabled}>
          <Text style={styles.text}>Modal centered</Text>
          <Button title="Disable" onPress={() => this.setState({isDisabled: !this.state.isDisabled})} />
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setState({isDisabled: !this.state.isDisabled})}>
            <Text>Disable</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </Modal>
```

Comment: Do you have another button on the screen with an onPress function that  sets State {isDisabled: true}?

Comment: should you use `this.setState({isDisabled: !this.state.isDisabled})` __*twice*__? if so, when `<Button onPress` the value of `isDisable` must be `true` but it will be change to `false` again when `<TouchableOpacity onPress` executed

Comment: I deleted the TouchableOpacity and it still does not work. Also, @corey I do not have another button on the screen with {isDisabled: true}

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean isDisabled. I was trying to look for a prop that would set the modal to visible similar to the visible prop on the react-native modal 
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/modal.html